# Bash, referring to array by value?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there some way to access a variable by referring to it by a value?

```
BAR=("hello", "world")

function foo() {

    DO SOME MAGIC WITH $1

    // Output the value of the array $BAR
}

foo "BAR"
```

Comment: What's it supposed to output?

Comment: It's supposed to output the content of the array -> ${BAR[@]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is indirect expansion. From `man bash`:

> If  the  first  character  of  parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the
>          value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that  value
>          is  used  in  the  rest  of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is known as indirect expansion.  The
>          exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The exclamation point must immediately  fol‐
>          low the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

Related docs: [Shell parameter expansion (Bash Manual)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and  [Evaluating indirect/reference variables (BashFAQ)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2BAC8-reference_variables).

Here's an example.

```
$ MYVAR="hello world"
$ VARNAME="MYVAR"
$ echo ${!VARNAME}
hello world
```

Note that indirect expansion for arrays is slightly cumbersome (because `${!name[@]}` means something else. See linked docs above):

```
$ BAR=("hello" "world")
$ v="BAR[@]"
$ echo ${!v}
hello world

$ v="BAR[0]"
$ echo ${!v}
hello
$ v="BAR[1]"
$ echo ${!v}
world
```

To put this in context of your question:

```
BAR=("hello" "world")

function foo() {
    ARR="${1}[@]"
    echo ${!ARR}
}

foo "BAR"  # prints out "hello world"
```

#### Caveats:

1. Indirect expansion of the array syntax will not work in older versions of bash (pre v3). See [BashFAQ article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2BAC8-reference_variables).
2. It appears you cannot use it to retrieve the array size. `ARR="#${1}[@]"` will not work. You can however work around this issue by making a copy of the array if it is not prohibitively large. For example:

   ```
   function foo() {
       ORI_ARRNAME="${1}[@]"
       local -a ARR=(${!ORI_ARRNAME})  # make a local copy of the array

       # you can now use $ARR as the array
       echo ${#ARR[@]}  # get size
       echo ${ARR[1]}   # print 2nd element
   }
   ```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. How would I do if I also wanted to get the length of the same array? This doesn't seem to work: -> ARR="${#1}[@]"

Comment: @Filibustr It is not possible in that form, but there are workarounds. see last section in my edits.

Comment: Your last section doesn't seem to work. When I output the second element, I get an empty row. The array only seem to have the first element populated. :/   -   I'm using: GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Ah, ok. So if I wanted to apply a new element to the original array, I'd have to add it to the copy, then loop through it and copy back to the original? What I'm really trying to do is make a push array function. :) Thanks for all the answers and for you guys taking your time.

Comment: Assigning/appending to an array using indirect expansion can get quite hairy. If your really need to do it, it might be cleaner to simply bite the `eval` bullet and do something like this: http://ideone.com/Kprob. Is there a reason why you need to push to an arbitrary array reference by name?

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to do that. I'm just making a few small helper functions - that will make my life easier when I'm writing larger scripts. Well, thanks again for your input and help! Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
BAR=("hello", "world")

function foo() {
  eval echo "\${$1[@]}"
}
foo "BAR"
```

Comment: The problem with (unnecessary) `eval` is that you open yourself up to all sorts of nastiness. Try `foo "BAR};ls;echo\${BAR"`. Now imagine `ls` replaced with something less benign. */paranoia*

Comment: sorry, but if eval is omitted output becomes ${BAR[@]} and, yes of course, eval must be manipulated with care :)

Comment: This kind of works, but further down the line I will also need to output the length of the array. How come this doesn't work? -> eval echo "\${#1[@]}"

Comment: @Filibustr You're missing a `$`. Try `eval echo "\${#$1[@]}"`

Comment: Ah, this works. Thanks! Although I'm always kind of reluctant of using eval - regardless of the language. It would be nicer though, if I could get the length based on the first solution.

Comment: @Stephane Your answer is not wrong. I've included the warning about eval only because it is too often used as a quick solution even when there are standard approaches to achieving a task. I'm fine with careful use of eval but do be warned that there are folks on [so] who downvote eval answers on sight. *(this comment is a repost - fixes typo that led to a misleading double-negative statement)*

Answer (score 0):

You can put your arrays into a dictionary matched with their names. Then you can look up this dictionary to find your array and display its contents.